# Issues with AAD authentication when two diffrent users attempt logon simultaneously

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an enterprise application which is registered with AAD. I experienced a strange issue when two different users on the same directory attempted to logon at the same time. As strange as it may appear I found only one was able to get authenticated and the other didn't.

It took forever for the second user to get the authenticated and it eventually timed out. In order to remove the obvious, I asked them to login one at a time. However, if the first one got connected, the second couldn't while the first still active.

I asked the first to sign out and then the second to logon and had his hurray! moment and for me its like a unsolved puzzle - Only one of the directory users is able to logon at a time.

What could possibly have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same PC for this?

Comment: Tried on same pc with a different incognito mode browser and also tried it on different pc

Comment: Same PC is obvious, the incognito windows are not different. They share cookies and thus login state. The different PCs should work fine unless you are doing something odd on your app's side.

Comment: Are these two accounts specific？Or you cannot sign in any two accounts at same time?

Comment: No, we tried. 
1. A and B together
2. B and C together
3. C and A together

At any given point only one user was also to get through the other gets either timed out or Bad Request.

Comment: @juunas  - I meant different browsers in incognito mode (chrome and firefox), wouldn't share their cookies. The app after authentication just redirects the user to a dashboard.

Comment: Where do you get the timeout / bad request? Azure AD or your app?

Comment: While logging on to Azure AD. After entering the user credentials, its returns with a Bad Request.

Comment: This is the error message --
Bad Request - Request Too Long  
 
HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

I've already tried the workarounds suggested in 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020943/http-400-bad-request-request-header-too-long-response-to-http-request

Comment: Hi, @ProjectMavericks . Did you tried to clear the cookie in the broswer? Please check this discussion:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100272/azure-portal-bad-request-request-too-long

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT   
 Yes I did, but to no avail.

Comment: @ProjectMavericks It seems this will require a further check in your environment to assist you with resolution. Did you already try to reach out Azure Support to work with you to resolve the issue? I can help you with opening one time free Azure Support ticket if you have limitations with Azure Support plan. If you want to go that route, please send email to AzCommunity@microsoft.com with reference to this SO thread link.