# Azure AD - Request too long

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I've created an application that uses Azure AD for  (not Azure AD B2C). I've been referencing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/master/ReadmeFiles/aspnetcore-webapp-tutorial-alt.svg?sanitize=true along the way.

Since i've deployed the application to our test environements, I randomly get 'HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long'.

I've come across [Azure Portal: Bad Request - Request Too Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100272/azure-portal-bad-request-request-too-long) but this solution is for Azure B2C.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Let me know if you need code examples. but i've pretty much followed the git repositories referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to TempData. Try to replace from cookie based to session based:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-the-tempdata-provider

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do so with MSAL?