# HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, model-view-controller, sitecore

I am trying to do authentication via Azure AD on my Sitecore Instance. I've added my application to the approved list by creating the App Service.

However after the login, the user is redirected to the `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` page on the Identity server and it displays the following error message:

> HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the headers in the request and see if there's anything obvious. Please include these request headers in your question.

Comment: The error HTTP 400: Size of header request is too long generally happens because there's too many cookies .Try clearing Cookies

Answer (score 0):

We have identified the issue the actual cause is:
Cookies that are too big as a part of the authentication request.

As a resolution to the problem:
Limit the amount of claims you include in your token.
For testing change the 
groupMembershipClaims: null in the manifest file on the azure ad will allow you to authenticate the request.

Reference:
[Azure Portal: Bad Request - Request Too Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100272/azure-portal-bad-request-request-too-long/46250877#46250877)