# Azure giving error with long URL with Token

Tags: reactjs, azure, web, react-router, web-config

I have hosted a front end app using React and React Router Dom to Azure.

I have a reset password link with token as below

https://abc.azurewebsites.net/reset/CfDJ8AkOTLe70aJDl6Jq93G40f4OoMX35xv1bg73%2fU9WyIDfJae9LcF8iFFF6oiO7atp8l9O%2fr1lBq%2bMPZd2aPkELXWPB7YQ5lYoAkh3t2QdB5a%2fB%2bRvJordH34lEbPRBV%2by842E5z%2b1ZNSBstZljGOPZ6tOQNjLGH%2byAAUURGK2Z8rSFjQa22t0RXaVTzP59yCEagf42DGK9UM1PLqtSun655EVkoRH8Jg2LtgK2YZYv6zD

This work fine with localhost. However in Azure it gives this error

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I have already added the web.config that was suggested in few posts. It works for shorter URL but not sure how to make it work for bigger urls with tokens.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength = "10000" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Please use below. It seems this was a bug and they fixed it in 2019 github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/3916

```html
<security> <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"> <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" maxUrl="8192" maxQueryString="2048"/> </requestFiltering> </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The error message is due to the length of the URL with the token.

Azure has a `default limit of 2048 characters` for URLs. You can increase the limit by adding the following configuration to your `web.config` file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength = "32768" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As per the
[Azure Web App URL Length Limitations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)
The increase in the maximum length of the **query string to 32768 characters**.

And you need to adjust the `maxQueryStringLength` value in the `httpRuntime` element to match the new limit you set in the `requestLimits` element.

**Approach 2**

```
const myToken = "long token"; 
const encoded_Token = encodeURIComponent(myToken); 
const reset_PasswordUrl = `https://somesample.com/reset-password/${encoded_Token}`;
```

And it is a good practice to ensure that the URL is properly formatted and can be parsed correctly by the server.

> If the token is too long, it may exceed the maximum URL length allowed by Azure. In this case, you need to consider using a POST request instead of a GET request to pass the token.

Alternatively, you can try shortening the token by using a tokenization service or by generating a shorter token.

**Another option** is `storing the token in a database` and passing a `unique identifier in the URL` instead of the entire token.

For further information refer to the SO [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100272/azure-portal-bad-request-request-too-long)

Comment: Thanks. I have already maxQueryStringLength = 10000. I assume it means # of characters. I only have about ~330 with token. I am also doing the encodeURIComponent ().

Comment: Not sure where its wrong

Comment: I think there must be some other configuration also. I am using HttpUtility.UrlEncode that converts the / to %2b etc. Once I remove those from url it works. 
But I have to pass it like that else react router dom does not work.

Comment: SOLVED:  Please use below. It seems this was a bug and they fixed it in 2019
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/3916
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" maxUrl="8192" maxQueryString="2048"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

Comment: got it...sorry...new to stackoverflow

Comment: Got it...thanks...New to StackOverflow